# How to open localhost:8000 using VPS Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, blockchain, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

hello I need help how to open `http://localhost:8000` from my pc. because my project polkadot substrate installed on a VPS Ubuntu, after I try to open `IP:8000` it also doesn't work

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um6el.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the substrate node using `--rpc-cors all` option. Please note that substrate chains don't expose websocket connections to the public internet without some hacking. I am assuming your question asks how to connect a substrate node running on a remote server to your local pc front end. If that's right let's continue:

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-wss

Describes the entire process. You need to install NGINX, configure `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and within the `http` code block insert the mentioned code, with proper variable replacements. Then generate a self-signed SSL certificate, and open port `9944` and `443` on your remote machine. Next visit the machine with `https://IP:443` to whitelist that site, and finally connect to your substrate node with a local installation of `polkadot-js-apps`. You cannot connect it using the online polkadot.js explorer , so you must use a local connection. And that should get you up and running.